# Scale an line svg as per height of the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am making an svg (a line element) and it's vertical. I want that svg line to scale according to the height of the container.

```
<div class="parent">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" style="stroke: black;stroke-width:1"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Now if increase parent width the height of vertical line scales, but the requirement is, as we increase the height, length should increase proportionally.
Am i putting the `viewBox` wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `vector-effect` attribute. If you set it to `non-scaling-stroke` - this will enable you to keep the stroke of the line at 1 pixel independent of the size of the svg. Take a look at this example below, I've set up the svg to fill the parent:

```css
.parent {
  background: #efefef;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" 
         style="stroke: black;stroke-width:1" 
         vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Try changing the size of the parent around and you'll notice that the stroke width always remains consistent.

Comment: Really helped, thanks!! i had to update viewbox = 0 0 0 100 though.

Answer (score 3):

Scale SVG proportionally:

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
}

.parent svg {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
100px height
<div class="parent" style="height: 100px;">
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 2 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:2"/>
    </svg>
</div>
300px height
<div class="parent" style="height: 300px;">
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 2 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:2"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Scale SVG but keep stroke

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
}

.parent svg {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
100px height
<div class="parent" style="height: 100px;">
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 2 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    </svg>
</div>
300px height
<div class="parent" style="height: 300px;">
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 2 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: when you increase the height stroke width increases